generate php code with mixed single quotes
I trying to echo php code
the problem in the single quotes in inside generated code
I  used &#39; but I want it in generated  code will be '
$start_trial='start trial';
$status=false;
if(!$status)  echo '<?php if(!$status) { echo &#39;<p class="trial_p_ix">'.$start_trial.'</p>&#39; ; } ?>'; 

generated code is
<?php if(!$status) { echo &#39;<p class="trial_p_ix">start trial</p>&#39; ; } ?>

but I want will be
<?php if(!$status) { echo '<p class="trial_p_ix">start trial</p>'; } ?>


Assuming you are very new to PHP, I would strongly advise AGAINST such code generation. Surely you can achieve your goal without it.

I have given you an answer below, but like YourCommonSense I do wonder why you are trying to do this, or what you are hoping to achieve by it. I would strongly suspect there is a better way to implement your system overall.

&#39; is HTML-encoding, so unless you specifically HTML-decode it, PHP won't do anything with that.
You can just escape the quote marks with \, though.
$start_trial='start trial';
$status=false;
if(!$status)  echo '<?php if(!$status) { echo \'<p class="trial_p_ix">'.$start_trial.'</p>\'; } ?>';

Working demo: https://3v4l.org/Sqc6m
